# What are the "Seams" in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, language-features, legacy-code

I'm reading "Working Effectively with Legacy Code", and was thinking about the "fancy" seams that he discusses in Chapter 4.

Since Actionscript 3 doesn't have method overloading, I was wondering what can be used as a seam in as3 besides the import statements and making subclasses?

For clarity, a seam is defined as :

> **Seam:** A seam is a place where you can alter behavior in your program
>   without editing in that place.

Thanks.

Comment: If I understood the example in book correctly, it involved overriding a function definition to alter behavior under test or in production. That is very well supported in AS3!

Comment: @catholicon You might be correct. Perhaps I was just confused by the linking.  Some reason  I thought he was talking about overloading not overriding functions.